# a affine hyperplane in normed space

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, affine-geometry

[image]

I was troubled by the above proof,how to conclude that $x^\prime=\frac{u}{\phi(u)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is in the plane passing through the origin, $x, y$. The vertex is the origin. Because $C$ is a cone, the intersection of that plane with $\partial C$ is two rays from the origin. $x', y', u, w$ are all points on this plane because they are linear combinations of $x, y$. Because both $u$ and $x'$ were chosen to lie on $\partial C$, (and on the same side), they both lie on the same ray. Which means $x' = ku$ for some $k$.

Since $x' \in H$, $$\phi(x') = 1\\\phi(ku) = 1\\k\phi(u) = 1\\k = \frac 1{\phi(u)}$$
So $x' = \dfrac u{\phi(u)}$.

Comment: Why $x^\prime$ is in $H$?

Comment: Since $H$ is an affine space, the entire line through any two points in it is also contained in it. $x', y'$ are on the line through $x, y$.

Comment: How to interpret the affine space?Is there exist a concise equivalent definition ?see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402527/definition-of-affine-normed-space?noredirect=1#comment6998923_3402527

Comment: Actually, you can define the concept by the property I mentioned: A subset of a vector space is an affine space if and only if for any two distinct points in it, it also contains the line through them. But affine subspaces are usually defined as translates of vector subspaces; $A \subset V$ is an affine subspace if there is a $p\in A$ such that $A - p := \{a - p\mid a \in A\}$ is a vector subspace of $V$. Affine spaces are just like vector spaces except for not having a distinguished point acting as the origin. Euclidean space is an affine space.